# How not to repeat this code in my models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have this piece of code in a model that sets a start date and end date according to the time of the day that the method is run.

Let's jump right into the code example:

```
#MODEL
now = Time.now
if now.hour >= 17 && now.hour <= 23
    #night
    n = now+1.day
    startd = Time.local(now.year, now.month, now.day, 17, 00, 00)
    endd = Time.local(n.year, n.month, n.day, 8, 00, 00)
elsif now.hour >= 0 && now.hour <= 7
    #morning
    n = now-1.day
    startd = Time.local(n.year, n.month, n.day, 8, 00, 00)
    endd = Time.local(now.year, now.month, now.day, 17, 00, 00)     
end
```

Then inside a model (same or another), I am trying to run this function inside a find.

```
#MODEL(SAME OR OTHER)
Model.find(:all, 
 :conditions => ['created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', startd, endd])
```

The problem is that I'm going to use that function to set the start and end dates a lot, and I dont know where to place it to not repeat myself. It's going to be used from different models.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include it in a module in the `lib` directory. All ruby files in RAILS_ROOT/lib are automatically loaded.

```
# time_calculations.rb

module TimeCalculations
  def calc_start_and_end_times
    now = Time.now
    if now.hour >= 17 && now.hour <= 23
        #night
        n = now+1.day
        startd = Time.local(now.year, now.month, now.day, 17, 00, 00)
        endd = Time.local(n.year, n.month, n.day, 8, 00, 00)
    elsif now.hour >= 0 && now.hour <= 7
        #morning
        n = now-1.day
        startd = Time.local(n.year, n.month, n.day, 8, 00, 00)
        endd = Time.local(now.year, now.month, now.day, 17, 00, 00)     
    end
    [startd, endd]
  end
end

# model.rb

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend TimeCalculations

  def self.my_find()
    startd, endd = calc_start_and_end_times
    Model.find(:all, 
      :conditions => ['created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', startd, endd])
  end

end
```

*Edited to reflect final/correct answer.*

Comment: This sounded like a good solution, I tried that one already but it gave me "undefined method `calc_start_and_end_times' for #<Class:0xb6f3bb30>" error. I included the module on top of my model class. Any idea?

Comment: Try changing def self.calc_start_and_end_times to def calc_start_and_end_times

I couldn't remember if you need self or not on the method definition.

Comment: Tried that too, sorry for not mentioning. It sounds like the model can't access the method from the Module.

Comment: Remove the "self." from the def in the module.  When you import the module, since you're trying to modify the class itself, use:  class << self import TimeCalculations end.  The import goes on its own line; I can't format code in a comment here.

Comment: Here we go. Remove the self in "def self.calc_..." and use "extend TimeCalculations" instead of "include TimeCalculations".  When you want to use class methods, you need extend. include is for instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to add your code to a module, maybe in an initializer:

```
module SmartDates

  def start_date
    now = Time.now
    if now.hour >= 17 && now.hour <= 23
      #night
      n = now+1.day
      return Time.local(now.year, now.month, now.day, 17, 00, 00)
    elsif now.hour >= 0 && now.hour <= 7
      #morning
      n = now-1.day
      return Time.local(n.year, n.month, n.day, 8, 00, 00)
    end
  end

  def end_date
    now = Time.now
    if now.hour >= 17 && now.hour <= 23
      #night
      n = now+1.day
      return Time.local(n.year, n.month, n.day, 8, 00, 00)
    elsif now.hour >= 0 && now.hour <= 7
      #morning
      n = now-1.day
      return Time.local(now.year, now.month, now.day, 17, 00, 00)
    end
  end

end

# Now include your module
ActiveRecord::Base.include(SmartDates)
ActionController::Base.include(SmartDates)
```

Now `start_date` and `end_date` are available in both models and controllers.

Comment: Thanks, the module code goes in /lib? What about the include code, where would you put it?

Comment: I'd probably put it in an initializer, as I mentioned above. In `config/initializers/smart_dates.rb` or something.  Maybe I'd put the module in lib/ and the includes in the initializer.

Answer (score 0):

you can add method find_by_date_range (startd, endd) inside model class and use Model.find_by_date_range(something, something_else)

Comment: So, where is the part that calculates the start and end datetime?

Comment: Let me explain. First of all you need to decide - will be start/end calculations used elsewhere in your code. If yes - it will be useful to move method, that responsible for calculations of start and end. Next step - develop find-method in your model, that will return all records by your criteria (erik have entered good example).
And yet another helpful solution - you can use named_scope - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/named_scope

Comment: correction for my comment - "If yes - it will be useful to move method, that responsible for calculations of start and end to the module, if not - it' not so necessary"